# Performance comparison between ECDSA and BLS signature schemes

Tags: signature, dsa, performance, bls-signature

I want to choose an efficient signature scheme for implementation on a lightweight MCU. I was wondering how does the performance of ECDSA and BLS signature schemes compare in terms of signing time and signature size, etc.?

Comment: By eyeballing the math behind both solutions, I'd like to say ECDSA (or better EdDSA) would be faster than BLS; but BLS is shorter. It would be nice to see some fair benchmarks. BLS has the disadvantage that pairing costs are approximate to some number of exponentiations. I'd need to read up on pairings.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it depends on various factors:

1. Which curves and which level of security is your target?
2. Which algorithms do you most frequently use key generation, signing, or verification?
3. Which microcontroller is your target?
4. Which compiler do you use?

But generally, based on [ECRYPT Benchmarking of Asymmetric Systems](https://www.ecrypt.eu.org/ebats/index.html) report on [March 2007](https://www.ecrypt.eu.org/ebats/D.VAM.9-1.1.pdf) performed on x86, 2400MHz, Intel Pentium 4 (page. 164-165):

[image: Comparison of Signature Schemes in Performance]

(ecdonald is an implementation of ECDSA and compared values are in CPU cycles)

BLS **signing algorithm** is **faster** than ECDSA-256 but it is **slower** in **key generation** and **verification**.

Comment: Hmmm, that ecrypt report is from 15 years ago - since then, we have found that pairing friendly curves didn't give the security we had, at the time, thought, and that to get that level of security, we needed to use somewhat larger curves.  If that test was on, say, BN-256, we now know that's an apples-to-oranges comparison (security-wise)

Answer (score 1):

Found this article that seems to answer your question:
https://www.dash.org/blog/bls-is-it-really-that-slow/

Comment: Welcome to crypto-SE, and thanks for finding and sharing that interesting link. However link-only answers are at least discouraged, see _“Provide context for links”_ in [how-to-answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).